# setNeedsDisplay is not updating UIView

Tags: ios, swift, drawrect

I have a circular progress bar in my app that displays the percentage of a user's budget that they have spent. It seems to work, however it doesn't update unless I close the app in multitasking and reopen it.

After doing some research I discovered that I should be reloading it with setNeedsDisplay, however this doesn't fix the issue.

Here is my drawRect() code:

```
var progress: CGFloat = 0

class ProgressCircle: UIView {

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    var ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    var innerRadiusRatio: CGFloat = 0.6

    var path: CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
    var startAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat(-M_PI_2)
    var endAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat(-M_PI_2) + min(1.0, progress) * CGFloat(M_PI * 2)
    var outerRadius: CGFloat = CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) * 0.5 - 1.0
    var innerRadius: CGFloat = outerRadius * innerRadiusRatio
    var center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect))

    //Code for background circle

    var context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, (UIColor.darkGrayColor()).CGColor)
    var rectangle: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 171, 171)
    CGContextBeginPath(context)
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle)
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill)

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, (UIColorFromRGB(0xEAEAEA)).CGColor)
    var rectangleSmall: CGRect = CGRectMake(35.95, 35.95, 99.1, 99.1) //102.6
    CGContextBeginPath(context)
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangleSmall)
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill)

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //Code for progress radius

    CGPathAddArc(path, nil, center.x, center.y, innerRadius, startAngle, endAngle, false)
    CGPathAddArc(path, nil, center.x, center.y, outerRadius, endAngle, startAngle, true)
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path)
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path)

    CGContextSaveGState(ctx)
    CGContextClip(ctx)
    if percent > 100 {
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, self.bounds, UIImage(named: "RadialProgressFillOver").CGImage)
    } else {
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, self.bounds, UIImage(named: "RadialProgressFill").CGImage)
    }
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx)
}
```

This is how I tried reloading the progress circle:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    //Show set up screen if user hasn't used AffordIt before.

    userReturned = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("userReturnedCheck")
    if userReturned == false {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("setupView", sender: self)
    }

    //Add circular progress bar to budget display view.

    progress = CGFloat(percent/100)
    var circleFrame = CGRect(x: 75, y: 249, width: 171, height: 171)
    var circle = ProgressCircle(frame: circleFrame)
    self.budgetDisplayView.addSubview(circle)
    self.budgetDisplayView.sendSubviewToBack(circle)
    circle.setNeedsDisplay()
    view.setNeedsDisplay()

    circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

Comment: Can we see the whole class?

Comment: The whole class that the viewWillAppear() is in? It's pretty huge... If you are talking about the ProgressCircle class, then that's the entire thing.

Comment: Just code that updates the progress indicator, sorry for not explaining that in my first comment.

Comment: Are you updating your progress bar anywhere else?  Because if that's the only place you update it, that explains everything because `viewDidAppear` is called when your view appears on the screen.

Comment: Nope. The only time that value of the progress circle can change is outside of the view with the progress circle. That's why I decided to put it in viewDidAppear().

Comment: I've just tried adding a refresh button to see if it would update. And it still doesn't seem to work.